# Problems withi18nextXHRBackend on client data served by node server

Tags: jquery, node.js, i18next

I am trying to move from v1 of i18next to v2 (https://github.com/i18next).
I managed to move my node-express code ad have it working, now I try on the front end, which are Jquery scripts, with data filled from Ajax calls to the node server.

It does not work, I get this error message - files have not moved and it works in v1

```
  " GET https://localhost:8800/locales/it-IT/translation.json 500 (Internal Server Error)
   i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language it-IT failed failed loading locales/it-IT/translation.json"
```

My Jquery code is

```
i18next.use(i18nextXHRBackend).init({
 compatibilityAPI: 'v1',
 compatibilityJSON: 'v1', 
 backend: {
    // path where resources get loaded from
    loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
},
 debug:true,lng: 'it-IT',fallbackLng : 'it' }, (err, t) => {
// and here continue with my code
```

I am doing something very wrong, but I cannot understand what, or what is going on.  I read the docs, many times, but still black hole.I use the compatibility to keep some parts of my code running until I modify everything

My server is a node server, same config as in v1. Could it be that I would need a web server to serve the statics files ? or that I should put something in my node server to serve them ?
Thanks for any hint, help, example, explanation

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the below line from my server code:

```js
app.get('/locales/:lng/:ns', i18nextMiddleware.getResourcesHandler(i18n));
```